# How are $rules resolved for date variable values

Tags: php, laravel

For the following $rules, `after:today` and `after:start_date` are resolved as expected. However, I do not understand, how it actually works but… I checked the code, but I can't figure it out. Laravel sends the value following `after:` through `strtotime`. Is `today` a predefined value for `strtotime`? But `start_date` is a key in the array I just created. How does that work?

```
public static $rules = array(
  'name' => 'required', 
  'description' => '', 
  'location' => 'required|alpha-dash', 
  'cost' => 'numeric|min:0', 
  'min_age' => 'numeric|min:0', 
  'max_age' => 'numeric|min:0', 
  'start_date' => 'required|date|after:today', 
  'end_date' => 'required|date|after:start_date', 
  'start_time' => 'required|time', 
  'end_time' => 'required|time', 
  'registration_start_date' => 'date', 
  'registration_end_date' => 'date', 
  'max_attendees'  => 'numeric|min:0'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the `validateAfter` method in `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`

```
protected function validateAfter($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // [unimportant code]

    if ( ! ($date = strtotime($parameters[0])))
    {
        return strtotime($value) > strtotime($this->getValue($parameters[0]));
    }

    return strtotime($value) > $date;
}
```

First it will check if if the first parameter is a some form of a date. in your case `today`. If it's not, it will call `$this->getValue` and use `strtotime` again. `getValue()` just returns the value of an attribute by it's name:

```
protected function getValue($attribute)
{
    if ( ! is_null($value = array_get($this->data, $attribute)))
    {
        return $value;
    }
    elseif ( ! is_null($value = array_get($this->files, $attribute)))
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

**Note** that this also means any parameter that can be interpreted by `strtotime` will be used as that. So if you had an attribute named `today`, not the value of the attribute but rather `strtotime('today')` would be used for validation

Comment: So $this->data contains the input fields that are being validated? That means that any of the input fields can be used in the $rules values?